# Jhipster Angular 4 additional CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jhipster

How do I add a custom CSS to the jhipster 4 project. Currently when I add a CSS file to the `content\css` folder and import it in `vendor.scss` it does not get imported. Similarly we need to import a JS file.

Comment: Please don't ping in questions or answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the global.css file in `src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css` and import your CSS files (use the @import balise). Or you can import them in the `vendor.ts` file too.

For example I have a custom modal.scss file, in my global.scss file I've put : 
`@import "modal";`

For your JS files, they should be in `src/main/webapp/app`.

Hope it helps you.